# mini fb posting to friend's wall using graph api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I have read all the other post relating to this but I think I am missing something fundamental. I am using mini_fb in my ruby on rails application for handling the facebook api. I have the following code:

```
current_user.session.post('me', :type => :feed, :params => {:name => "name",
                                                        :to => "{\"data\":[{\"name\":\"#{friend.facebook_name}\",\"id\":\"#{friend.facebook_id}\"}]}",
                                                        :link => url_of_app,
                                                        :description => "desc",
                                                        :actions => "{\"name\": \"action name\", \"link\": \"url\"}"})
```

The above posts to the current user's wall with or without the "to" parameter set. Everything works, except for the "to" parameter. I have read the graph post to wall over and over again and I can't figure out what is wrong with this code of mine. I would really appreciate it if someone could point out my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used ruby's version, but probably the problem is in the first parameter. You are targeting 'me' feed, while should be targeting your friends feed. Try fetching your friend id and doing something like

```
current_user.session.post(friend.facebook_id, :type => :feed, :params => ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, mini_fb looks so verbose :)

Telémako is right, you need to use your friends id. I give you another alternative for more nice code. Use Koala.

https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Graph-API

```
@graph.put_wall_post("explodingdog!", {:name => "i love loving you", :link => "http://www.explodingdog.com/title/ilovelovingyou.html"}, "tmiley")
=> {"id"=>"83901496_520908898070"}
```

I use it in my projects and works very well.